# Fetch Core Data object from UITableViews not made from Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to fetch a Core Data object and load it from a `UITableView` that is NOT made up from Core Data objects. It's simply a `UITableView` made with a predetermined array, but I want to load an object in Core Data with the same name as the cells `detailTextLabel`. I tried following [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW5) to load a specific value, but it's not working: It crashes or tells me my entity is `nil`, which it's not.

So basically I have a `UITableView` and it loads with this array:

```
array = @[@"publication 1",@"publication 2", etc]
```

Then, when a user selects the cell, I would like it to load a document based on the cells `detailText`, but it always loads whatever the objects `indexPath` is, instead of based on the cells `detailText`. So say in the main view controller where the predetermined array is loaded into the table view, I tap on Memo 24, but its index is (0,2) it **will load an object**, but it will load the object in the downloads entity that has the same `indexPath` (whatever publication is at 0,2) number as opposed to the Memo 24 title.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self loadPublicationLocallyWithPubAtIndex:indexPath withTitle:cell.detailTextLabel.text];
}

- (void)loadPublicationLocallyWithPubAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withTitle:(NSString *)pubNumber {
    NSManagedObjectContext *selectedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *phrase = nil; // Document password (for unlocking most encrypted PDF files)
    NSString *filePath;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDFs"];
    filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[selectedObject valueForKey:@"puburl"]]; assert(filePath != nil); ;
    NSLog(@"Local path is : %@", filePath);
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        //File exists
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        if (data)
        { 
            //load document
        }
    }
}
```

It works for all my view controllers that populate with Core Data, no matter what `indexPath` the cell is, it still retrieves the right object, so that leads me to believe it has something to do with the `[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndex:];` part, so I even tried:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedItem = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:cell.detailTextLabel.text];
```

in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, but it doesn't work either.

How do you load an object based on a cells `detailTextLabel` as opposed to its `indexPath`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are populating your array from a static array, then you probably don't need to use a fetched results controller.  You should instead just execute a fetch to get the relevant NSManagedObject.  To ensure the fetch gets only the relevant object, use a predicate.

Suppose your NSManagedObjects are in a `Publication` Entity, and the relevant attribute is `title`.  You should build a fetch like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext; // or however your context is obtained
NSManagedObject *selectedObject;
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Publication"]; // amend entity name as appropriate
fetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@",pubNumber];
NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
if (results == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Fetch error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
} else {
    if ([results count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Publication not found");
    } else {
        // (note, should probably also check for count > 1 and handle accordingly)
        selectedObject = results[0];
        // then carry on with the remaining code from loadPublicationLocally....
        NSString *phrase = nil; // Document password (for unlocking most encrypted PDF files)
        NSString *filePath;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDFs"];
        filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[selectedObject valueForKey:@"puburl"]]; assert(filePath != nil); ;
        // ... etc etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been trying to use an NSPredicate for 3 days now. Your a life saver, i am new to coding (obviously) and most of my code was obtained through SO, so hopefully this answer will help future question seekers! thanks thanks thanks

Comment: and thank you for commenting it out and explaining things